# tkinter python change a listbox file's name without changing the file directory of that file

Tags: python, file, tkinter, filepath

I'm running into this problem where whenever I import a file into my Listbox it makes the name of the item in the listbox C:\blahblah\blahblah\test.txt
which is annoying since I only want the "test" or test.txt" to be shown in the listbox but still not disturb the file directory, Is This Possible?

I'm using from tkinter import * btw

there isnt much ive tried since as soon as i change the name of the file, the file directory follows with it.

example :

```
window = Tk()

list = []

listbox = ListBox(window)
listbox.pack()

filedirectory = os.listdir("blahblah/")
for f in filedirectory:
    listbox.inset("end", f"blahblah/{f}") #where it says blahblah is an example of where you could "potentially" change the name but that changes the file directory with it

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please share what you have tired(You code)? I can't give you any suggestions also, without looking at your code.

Comment: Use `import os.path`, then `os.path.basename(f)` inside your for loop. Also there's a typo in your example. `listbox.inset` should be `listbox.insert`.

Comment: If the text file is in the same directory as the python file, then you can simply use `test.txt` instead of providing full path

Comment: yeah, but as an executable file it would look pretty weird to have 30 files with the exe file but yes that does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer credit goes to Henry's comment but I have added what you are asking for in comment.

> How to get rid of extensions?

Here's the complete solution:

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path

window = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(window)
listbox.pack()

filedirectory = os.listdir("<path>")
for f in filedirectory:
    listbox.insert("end", f"{os.path.basename(f).split('.')[0]}")

window.mainloop()
```

There were some typos in your question, I have fixed those as well. First is `ListBox` which should be `Listbox` and second is `insert` not `inset` .

Comment: ill try this out and get back to you later! ill mark answer if worked (which it probably does) Thank You either way!

Comment: Okay! I am waiting for response.

Comment: I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the delay, it’s just I’m planning a program and gathering all the potential issues and this was one of them, please be patient and don’t worry about this as I will be sure to get back to it

Comment: oh ok, i see what you did here, so you basically just kept the "name" of the file, this did indeed work but i had some issues connected a button to it, so what i tried is a got your idea and basically made a list so it kept the value, so yes this does work but it gave me trouble connecting buttons, which i resolved with the help of this! Thank You. (sorry for the time being)